# Create GD.php image and post to album using fb.api / fb.ui

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos, image-uploading

All the examples I've seen use the old $facebook->api for album and uploading an image.

ie, old api//$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

What would the new api call be? FB->setFileUploadSupport(true);

Is there anyone that have an idea what the new methods are for creating album, and uploading an image to the album just created?

Any help?

Comment: Here is an awesome answer that someone posted on this very site not long ago... hope it helps.. but I cant take credit for the answer
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/3006867/558021

Comment: You should try out the search feature on StackOverflow - many times others have also faced similar problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api)

Comment: It is using $facebook->api, not the FB.api

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two calls to facebook.

1) create an album
2) post to the recently created album

Scenario 1: A post request to `/me/albums` with access_token, name parameters will create an album

```
curl -F \ "access_token=..."  \ -F "name=name of album...." \ "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums
```

This will return an album_id

Scenario 2: A post request to `/album_id/photos` with access_token, message, source

```
curl -F \ "access_token=..."  \ -F "message=..." \ -F "source=@/home/user/abc.jpg" "https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos
```